# Constrain violation Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I get a NOT NULL constraint violation exception when trying to insert an foreign key of
type Master Key in the DB.

How to avoid Constraint Violation Exception : Actually i created Two fields with same   column like

```
@Column(name = "dma_id") // It could accept null values
public long getDmaByDmaIds() {
   return dmaByDmaIds;
}

public void setDmaByDmaIds(long dmaByDmaIds) {
    this.dmaByDmaIds = dmaByDmaIds;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "dma_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) // I am ignoring entire fetch and store  
@JsonIgnore
public Dma getDmaByDmaId() {
    return this.dmaByDmaId;
}

public void setDmaByDmaId(Dma dmaByDmaId) {
    this.dmaByDmaId = dmaByDmaId;
}
```

In Database DMA(field)id accepting null values, but it's giving error.

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you schema is allowing `dma_id` to be null?

Comment: Yes Schema is allowing dma_id values I inserted manually also.

Comment: First of all, how do you plan to have a primitive long set to null? You should use Long. But why do you have this field in the first place, since you already have a ManyToOne association to Dma?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks i am unable to notice samll mistake Thank you very much

Comment: Because i required only **Foriegn Key ** I don't require entire _Object_ ...